# Launch a .bat script on a Window machine from a Unix machine

Tags: windows, unix, batch-file

I have two machines, a Windows one and a Unix box. I'm looking for a way to execute a .bat file on the Windows machine from the Unix one. Is this possible?
The machines are on the same network and I can share a directory from the Windows one the the Unix one if this can be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, presumably run an ssh server like [copssh](https://www.itefix.no/i2/copssh) on the windows box - this should allow you to use ssh to invoke the bat file and enable filesharing over scp as well

Comment: I succeeded using freeSSHd (http://www.freesshd.com/). Thanks for the hint.